# Article or answer to whether "blood volume pressure" and "electrodermal activity" have any correlation to stress and or feelings overall

Tags: electrophysiology, literature

As the title suggests, I would like some help finding if there is any correlation between between blood volume pressure and electrodermal activity?

The paper I'm writing is about measuring stress and engagement levels of the subject by comparing the levels of electrodermal activity and blood volume pressure during media consuming. This can be anything from music, movies, tvshows etc.

But the papers im looking for can be about the correlation only. Not by measuring the same type of things as I do.

If you know any good articles, I don't really care much about the publication date.

I have full access to ieee articles through university.

Thanks.

Comment: Questions should be specific and not lead to discussions. Also, please minimize the use of acronyms. I'm very interested in skin conductance and stress, so I would be happy to look into your issue, but as it stands this question does not meet this site's standards. Please edit and refine the question if you would like to receive input. The help center contains info on what a proper question format is. Have a look!

Comment: Okey, updated the answer now.

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand What Christiaan pointed out still stands. What correlation are you looking for? Do you want background on how the two are linked, or interpretation of stats from a certain paper?

Comment: @James i would prefer both, but one of them is enough. I'm writing a paper myself that include these points of measure and need to have facts that back up how they are linked. So a graph or short text describing it would be superb.

Comment: @SimonNilssonGuldstrand If you could incorporate that into your question and explain specifically the information you are looking for and add the `reference request` tag. If you don't make it clear, the question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Please see the [tag wiki](http://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) for reference-requests and provide the necessary information as mentioned there.

Comment: I have updated this question as much as I can. Are you guys still interested in helping me find an answer? @Christiaan